# Getting Data out of Angular ui-grid

Tags: angular-ui-grid

A question:

Does anyone know how to get data out of angular ui-grid ***in the currently displayed sorted order?***

I found out how to access data out of the grid using `gridApi.grid.rows`, but those rows do not appear to be sorted per the current sort order applied to the grid.

I feel like the grid is taunting me...showing me data in sorted order, but refusing to allow me to access it! Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `gridApi.grid.sortByColumn(gridApi.grid.rows)`?

Comment: This saved me! Why is this not in any examples?

Answer (score 0):

O Sean that's hot.

But will that re sort the data? Ideally id just be able to get at the data in its already sorted state.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to get the sorted data out of `gridApi`. `sortByColumn` will re-run the same sorting algorithm that the grid had previously used and return the data without mutating the graph, effectively giving you what you're looking for.

Comment: This seems like poor design on part of angular ui grid... But yes this does solve my problem! One gold star for you + a bottle of wuju.